# Verificar quando variável global sofre alteração

Tags: c#

Pessoal estou com o seguinte problema, possuo uma variável global `public static bool HouveAlteracaoBD { get; set; }` e preciso monitorar ela quando houver alguma alteração em seu valor, pois pretendo seguir a seguinte lógica:

```
if(Houve alteração na variável global "HouveAlteracaoBD" == true)
{
    CadEmpresaEntity cadEmpresa = new CadEmpresaFacade().GetCadEmpresa(empresaId, ref resultado);
    cadEmpresa.Ativa = true;
    new CadEmpresaFacade().Alterar(cadEmpresa, ref resultado);
}
```

O meu problema esta na expressão do if, que preciso esperar a variável global sofrer uma alteração, porém não sei como fazer isso, se alguém puder ajudar eu agradeço.

Comment: Variável "global"? Em que escopo? Qual classe esta variável pertence?

Comment: Ela se encontra na mesma classe deste trecho que eu coloquei acima, porém o código que altera o valor dela esta em outro controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode aproveitar o acessor `set` da propriedade. Guarde o valor real da propriedade em um campo a parte e utilize a propriedade para encapsular seu acesso, assim:

```
public class Foo
{
    private static bool houveAlteracao;

    public static bool HouveAlteracao
    {
        get { return houveAlteracao; }
        set
        {
            if (!houveAlteracao && value) // valor alterado para true
            {
                // lógica
            }
            else if (houveAlteracao && !value) // valor alterado para false
            {
                // lógica, caso deseje fazer algo nesse caso também.
            }

            houveAlteracao = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Como lógica você pode utilizar o corpo do `if` que mostrou na pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

Existe uma Interface específica para isso - INotifyPropertyChanged que possui um membro PropertyChanged que é um evento que podemos se inscrever.

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string imageFullPath;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, e);
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public string ImageFullPath
    {
        get { return imageFullPath; }
        set
        {
            if (value != imageFullPath)
            {
                imageFullPath = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ImageFullPath");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Referência: [Link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246777/raise-an-event-whenever-a-propertys-value-changed/2246837#2246837[/Link]

Comment: Por favor, dê os devidos créditos [à resposta da qual você copiou o código](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2246837/4190610).

Comment: Desculpe, não foi a intenção, estava com a mesma dúvida para fazer isso no Xamarin e acabei colando o que tinha acabado de achar! Vou me atentar a isso nas próximas! ;) @LINQ

Answer (score 1):

Como é um caso aparentemente simples, é possível definir isto no método `set` da propriedade.

```
public class SuaClasse
{
    private bool houveAlteracaoBd;

    public bool HouveAlteracaoBD
    {
        get { return houveAlteracaoBd; }
        set
        {
            if(value != houveAlteracaoBd)
            {
                houveAlteracaoBd = value;

                if(value) //Se for true
                    HouveAlteracao();
            }
        }
    }

    private void HouveAlteracao()
    {
        CadEmpresaEntity cadEmpresa = new CadEmpresaFacade().GetCadEmpresa(empresaId, ref resultado);
        cadEmpresa.Ativa = true;
        new CadEmpresaFacade().Alterar(cadEmpresa, ref resultado);
    }
}
```